# Sphinx - Get function documentation without the signature

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a python script that I'm documenting with Sphinx. One of the inputs to the script is a text file that I parse in a separate function, let's say `parse_file(f)`. The docstring for `parse_file` is where this text format is documented. I document the command line arguments using [sphinx-argparse](http://sphinx-argparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). So my RST looks something like this:

```
.. argparse::
    :module: mypkg.my_script
    :func: get_parser
    :prog: my_bash_wrapper.sh

.. autofunction:: mypkg.my_script.parse_file
```

I get almost what I want, but obviously the function has a signature in the documentation, but my command line users won't care about that. I've looked around the autodoc documentation and there are a lot of ways of overriding the signature to some other signature, but all seem to require some actual content and not an empty string. I can't seem to find a way to have no signature.

Does anyone know of a way to get what I'm after or do I have to resort to putting the function docstring in the sphinx? Thanks in advance.